# Cannot Create Instance Template

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am trying to create an instance template and am running into an issue of not being able to choose a network.  Nothing exists in the drop down box!

I've looked through the documentation to try to see if there is another area that I have to create a 'Network' in, but I can't seem to find it, if it exists.

Here's a screen shot of what I see when I am logged in and trying to create an instance template.

[image: create instance template - networking tab]

I guess my question is:  what am I missing here?

Comment: I found the way to create a network in the networking tab.  I swore I looked everywhere.  xD

Answer (score 1):

I know you have solved your problem, but for future reference or anyone come across this question, you can create a new network by accessing `Networking > Networks > Create Network` on Google Cloud console.

There is also the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#user-created_networks) on how to create networks and how they work